# Needing nullable parameter in .net mvc controller even tho always called with value

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

So my web application always made the hosting shut down the pool with 503 errors (probably rapid failure). My hosting sent me this piece.

```
^? Exception type: ArgumentException 
^? Exception message:^?The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'pageNum' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult AjaxFetch(Int32, Int32)' in 'Frontend.Controllers.BlogController'. An optional para
```

And the signature for that method is

(no attributes above, can be called with get)

```
public ActionResult AjaxFetch(int pageNum, int pageSize)
```

Now this is all very easy, i can simply change the ints to int? and voila. And thats what I did. My questions is of curiosity. Why did it fail, since I only ever call this function from js/jquery with the params set. And therefore the code always worked. But apperantly generated errors in the background. Why is that. no one was calling it with null and yet it failed with that.

Finally I will include my routing just so that there is no glitch there, here are both my routes, I have nothing else

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "stalkSaveOld",
            url: "geoshare",
            defaults: new { controller = "Stalk", action = "SaveCoordinate" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And btw the AjaxFetch is in BlogController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why did it fail, since I only ever call this function from js/jquery with the params set.

My guess is that *something else* (a robot?) is calling it without including all the parameters.

I'd suggest changing it to use the nullable types for the moment, but fail with an error if you detect that either value is null, after logging diagnostic information (user agent, client IP address, full request URL).

Comment: I was thinking about robot, but thing is. We are developing this page now. The odds are not super high for a robot finding the url. It's been at the current domain for less than 3 days (and started failing right away). But I guess anything is possible. I did nullable now to solve it. I was simply curious to if there was a reason I did not see in why it failed.

Comment: @RickardLiljeberg: Curiosity is a good thing, certainly - and hopefully by adding more diagnostics, you'll discover the reason :)